# Input string choice

Tags: java, string

So I'm a beginner in Java right now and I've been playing around with strings a bit. Now I'd like to give the user an input choice `"Enter a or b: "` and give an output based on either `"a"` or `"b"`

The Code:

```
int a = 18;
int b = 22;

Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

String first_name;
System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
first_name = user_input.next();

String last_name;
System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
last_name = user_input.next();

String full_name;
full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;
System.out.println("You are: " + full_name);

String age;
System.out.println("Enter a or b: ");
age = user_input.next();

String age_a;
System.out.println("Your age is 18");
age = user_input(a);
```

I was also thinking maybe a function could be used like:

```
if(user_input = a)
{
   System.out.println("Your age is 18.");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: The most duplicated Java question ever

Comment: Yea, well if you're a complete beginner and don't even know what to search for, it might get a bit difficult to find anything. I have been looking for a solution for 30min, before posting. So yea, -1 vote me for wanting to learn please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have `age` you must check the value, but as it is a `String` you **MUST** use `String.equals()`

```
if (age.equals("a"))
   System.out.println("Your age is 18");
else 
   System.out.println("Your age is 22");
```

If you want to check the answer is **ONLY** `a` or `b` use a while loop to repeat the question until answer is the desired:

```
String age;
while (!age.equals("a") || !age.equals("b")) {
    // ask for age
}
```

Comment: Oh, age.equals is truly something new for me. No idea you could do that. It works now, but why is my `if` underlined and says "Convert to switch"?

Comment: Because `switch(age) case "a"` sometimes is better, but this will be next step ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an if with `"string".equals("other_string")` to compare them:

```
int a = 18;
int b = 22;

Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
String first_name = user_input.next();

System.out.println("Enter your last name: ");
String last_name = user_input.next();

String full_name = first_name + " " + last_name;
System.out.println("You are: " + full_name);

System.out.println("Enter a or b: ");
String ageChoice = user_input.next();

String age = null;
if(ageChoice.equals("a")){
    age = String.valueOf(a);
}
else if(ageChoice.equals("b")){
    age = String.valueOf(b);
}
System.out.println("Your age is: " + age);
```

Comment: why did you capitalize `equals()` and `valueOf()`?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Edited. Currently working on a .NET project for over 6 months now, so I'm kinda used to capital methods by now. :)